# Tooltip is not showing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

Using the following JavaScript function I managed to show a static Tooltip with an arrow on hover.

```
   $('.tooltip-basic').hover(function () {
      var title = $(this).attr('title');
      $(this).data('title', title).removeAttr('title');
      $('<p class="tooltip-basic-message"></p>').text(title).appendTo(this).fadeIn('slow');
   }, function () {
      $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('title'));
      $('.tooltip-basic-message').remove();
   });
```

However, I am struggling to position the arrow under the tooltip, and position the tooltip above its div no matter what height it has.

**Here is a Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/xA8LS/3/

Answer (score 1):

First off, the `abbr` element should be a `block` level element.

```
.tooltip-basic {
    position: relative;
    display:block;
}
```

Second, the `:before` pseudo element should be absolutely positioned - not relatively.

```
.tooltip-basic-message:before {
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #285A98;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:-6px;
    left: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Aside from that, some of the positioning needed to be changed.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/VP6DH/)

---

Additionally, if you want the arrow centered:

[**Alternative Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/NTNEL/)

```
.tooltip-basic-message:before {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -2.5px;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use JavaScript to position the tooltip always on the top of its trigger element

Comment: @Leo That's exactly what it does in the examples above... or do you want it to follow the cursor?

Answer (score 1):

in my experience
in some cases tooltip will not display properly because of responsiveness, so if it's an in table item you should use

```
     $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
            container: 'table',
    });
```